# Centralized Indexing on Server for Window7 Search

Tags: search, windows-7, solr, indexing, network-drive

I have read this interesting article
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-7/Exploring-Windows-7s-New-Search-Features-Part1.html
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-7/Exploring-Windows-7s-New-Search-Features-Part2.html
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-7/Exploring-Windows-7s-New-Search-Features-Part3.html

This article ends with "*Sadly though, if you want to index network locations then you will be forced to cache the locations that you want to index. Searches of network volumes are still possible even without indexing those locations, but require a bit more effort than a typical search.*"

I have plenty of files in a network drive and searching is very slow and misses files and I wish to have them indexed so that I can have fast searches. The files may be edited from time to time (so the indexing must be updated with the changes etc). Making the files  available offline is not an option a sit would defeat the purpose of a network drive.

I was wondering is there a solution for this problem like some software that runs on an independent machine and windows search from workstations connect to this machine while doing searches on the network drive?

I've searched a bit and there are software that can index files such as Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ which is built on lucene.

Is there any software out there that does the whole thing?
Anyone ever done something like this? 
and if its not possible, why?

Comment: http://blog.trifork.com/2011/05/05/indexing-your-samba-windows-network-shares-using-solr/ might help you